# Echad Ushloshim Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred thirty one?

### אחד ושלושים ושלוש מאות - מי יודע?‏

The traditional Passover song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea) implies a possible presupposition that there is a Jewish significance to be found for each [natural number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number). Accordingly, there is an [ongoing series](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) on Mi Yodeya that is attempting to unearth significant Judaism facts about each number, in sequence.

What significant Judaism facts are there about the number 331? The more significant within Judaism and the more intrinsically dependent on the value 331, the stronger the answer. Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

I'm asking these questions, not to get lazy gematria answers, but to provide a haven for those who know numbers in Judaism, and to fire the imagination of those who want to learn more.

Comment: Some Christian sources I see online claim that there were 331 years from _Y'hoshua_'s death until _Shaul_'s reign. I can't seem to corroborate that, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number of days in a "normal" year in which Zionist Jews in chutz-laaretz don't say full Hallel:

Number of days in a "normal" year = 354

Days of full Hallel  in C"L = 21

"Zionist" full Hallel (Yom Haatzmaut and Yom Yerushalayim) = 2

354-21-2 = 331

Answer (score 5):

[Be'er Yitzchak](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6714&st=&pgnum=92&hilite=) quoting Shiurei Torah - Rabbi Chaim Noeh Zatzal - says that the minimum measurement for a Kosher Mikva is 331 liters and 776 grams.

Answer (score 0):

In was [reported](https://books.google.com/books?id=K5oeAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA523&dq=warsaw) in August 1853 that the [London Society for Promoting Christianity Among the Jews](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Society_for_Promoting_Christianity_Among_the_Jews) had claimed that, in Warsaw, 331 Jews had converted to Protestantism.

Comment: What does that have to do with Judaism?

Comment: Yishai, it's about people who left it. That said, there are other [tag:mi-yodeya-series] answers with much weaker Judaism connections, including my own answers. Historically, I think, we've been more lenient with answers in this series, but anyone should certainly downvote and vote to delete who deems it appropriate.

Comment: Our sense of on-topic, particularly to the non-inclusion of "history of the Jews," [started getting codified](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/178/2) after [most of](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series?page=2&sort=newest&pagesize=50) this series had already run. That, plus the difficulty of finding good Judaism answers for various numbers, explains the presence of many historical answers that we'd now consider off-topic. I won't downvote this one due to your justification, but I won't upvote it either, because it's at best borderline.